# Unable to run commands in a linux shell

Tags: linux

I am able to login to linux shell, but running commands don't do anything except the "bash" command. I am not sure where to look to enable the commands.

I tried commands like "whoami", "ls", "vi", "cat" etc, but no luck.

Any ideas, how to unlock myself?

Comment: What is the response? Error message? Anything? Do bash builtins work? `type` and `echo` should be builtins. What is the output of `type -a whoami`? If no error message after `whoami`, what is the exit status? (`echo $?` just after). What is the output of `echo "$PATH"`?

Comment: The response is empty. no error message for any of the above commands. The built-ins aren't working either.

Comment: What does `bash` do? (so you can tell it's different). Do you see any command prompt? and characters you type? Does invoking `reset` change anything?

Comment: `bash` takes me to the users prompt. `reset` didn't change anything. it cleared the screen. I see the characters i type.

Comment: "takes me to the user's prompt" -- So is there no prompt until you run `bash`? Do commands work in this new Bash? Does `echo foo >&0` generate output? (check both before and after you run `bash`).

Comment: How about pasting some output text? This sounds very mysterious

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  `echo foo >&0` does not print anything before running bash. After running `bash`, it prints `foo`

Comment: Thanks, @KamilMaciorowski  I am able to solve this issue. All I needed was to retrieve the contents of a file. and I was able to do that using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess somewhere in your startup scripts the standard output is redirected elsewhere (e.g. `exec 1>/dev/null`).

A temporary fix is to blindly type `exec 1>&0` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will redirect the standard output to what your standard input points to (normally this should be the console).

A permanent solution is to locate and delete the troublesome line. You will be able to do this after applying the temporary fix.